# Why Shell script runs with dangling '}'?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I wrote this script to compile and run my C and java programs with a single command.

```
     1   run(){
     2      gcc -lm $1 && ( shift; ./a.out $* )
     3     }
     4
     5   jrun(){
     6      clas=`echo $1 | cut -d'.' -f1 `
     7      javac $1 && { shift; java $clas $* }
     8   }
```

But on running getting error.

```
# source t.sh
-bash: t.sh: line 9: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Script run successfully when I added `'}'`  at the end.

Just realized that I used `{}` instead of `()` in `line 7`.

My question is why it run and work fine with a danging `'}'`?

Comment: Nothing is dangling. The last `}` completes the `jrun{}`.

Comment: Please don't post code with line numbers.

Comment: post with line number because error indicates the line number.

Comment: We can count, and the numbers make it tedious to copy/paste for experiments or commentary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a semicolon after the `$*` to separate the brace. As it is, it's simply interpreted as an argument to `javac`.

As an aside, you are probably looking for

```
run(){
   gcc -lm "$1" || return
   shift
   ./a.out "$@"
   }

jrun(){
   javac "$1" || return
   local clas=${1%.*}
   shift
   java "$clas" "$@"
 }
```

which fixes the many quoting issues, and avoids the slightly clumsy compound commands. The `local` declaration prevents the function from clobbering a global variable with the same name, but is a bashism.

Comment: As a further aside, this looks vaguely like it wants to be a `Makefile`.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is with your block - you're missing a semicolon.

It can be reproduced with this example:

```
true && { echo } # missing semicolon
```

If you run this in an interactive terminal, the shell will be left waiting to receive further input. If you enter an extra closing brace, then you will see the output of `echo }`:

```
}
```

Due to the way the shell parses, there needs to be a newline or semicolon between the last statement and the curly brace before the end of a block.

```
true && { echo; } # works
```

Answer (score 3):

> My question is why it run and work fine with a danging '}'?

It doesn't.  The code you presented is *missing* one `}`.  You need to add one before `bash` will accept it.

The problem is on line 7:

```
    javac $1 && { shift; java $clas $* }
```

`{` and `}` are not a shell metacharacters.  Their significance is context-dependent, and in particular, they can appear unescaped in or as ordinary shell words.  The `}` on the faulty line is therefore an argument to the `java` command, not a closing brace.  You want either this:

```
    javac $1 && { shift; java $clas $*; }
```

or this:

```
    javac $1 && {
      shift
      java $clas $*
    }
```

or some variation on those.